# Bayesian model averaging in R

Tags: r, bayesian, logistic, nls, model-averaging

I have a logistic model that I've built with the `nls` function in R. I want to use Bayesian model averaging for variable selection, but I can't find a package for that in R. Are there any suitable packages? If not, is it possible to make a not too complicated script for it?

Data example:

```
y<-sample(c(1,0),100,replace=T)

var1<-sample(c(1,0),100,replace=T)

var2<-sample(c(1,0),100,replace=T)

var3<-sample(c(1,0),100,replace=T)
```

The model:

```
Sw<- function(y1, N1,N2,N3) {

   SA <- nls(y1~exp(c+(a1*N1)+(a2*N2)+(a3*N3))/(1+exp(c+(a1*N1)+(a2*N2)+(a3*N3)))
    ,start=list(a1=-0.2,a2=-0.2,a3=-0.2,c=0.2))
   SA   
}



model <- Sw(y, var1,var2,var3)
```

How would I do Bayesian model averaging on this? I have 190 observations, where about 70 are `1`s and 120 are `0`s. I have 13 variables in total.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/BMA/index.html should help, i think.

Comment: I don't know about whether there is any package that handles BMA, but if you have a script with MCMC for you Bayesian problem, that you can obtain marginal likelihoods (and consequentely to do BMA) by so called power posteriors:
"Friel N, Pettitt AN. Marginal likelihood estimation via power posteriors. Journal of Royal Statistical Society: Series B (Statistical Methodology) 70, 589-607 (2008)"
Also, the implementation of the method in this paper is not difficult by BUGS program.

Comment: Model averaging of any flavor only makes sense if you have > 1 model - oh, so you have several runs of your function using different variables for N1, N2, and N3?

Comment: nls() isn't doing Bayesian estimation. If you're not needing a Bayesian perspective, you might check out package AICcmodavg. It doesn't work with nls objects, but perhaps could give you some ideas on how to do it by hand. Do you need Bayesian model averaging, or just plain ol' model averaging?

Comment: What is the purpose of your analysis? prediction of future data or inference about the structure in the data you have?  If this is for prediction, penalisation/shrinkage is probably better.

Comment: R Package BMS is another package to do Bayesian Model Averaging in R; see http://bms.zeugner.eu/ for more details.

Comment: The purpose of the analysis is to make inference about the data. I'm not sure about the difference between "plain ol' model averaging" and Bayesian. But the reason to why I want to do it is because I have a lot of variables and not enough data, so when I do model selection based on AIC it is really un-stable. With just adding or removing a few data points the final model changes.

Comment: @hbaghishani those are interesting packages but they won't help mael because they are not working with a set of fitted models, but directly with the underlying data assuming particular type of model (lm() in the case of BMS, unless I misunderstand the tutorial).